# I want to display the names of the parents linked to the children's table

Tags: laravel

I want to display the names of the parents linked to the children's table

`$listeEnfant= Enfant::where('Enfant_id', '=' , $id)
                        ->join('Parent','Parent.id_parent', '=','Enfant.parent1_id')
                        ->join('Parent','Parent.id_parent', '=','Enfant.parent2_id')
->get();`

SQLSTATE [42000]: Erreur de syntaxe ou violation d'accès: 1066 Table / alias non unique: 'parent'

Answer (score 1):

You should setup [Relationships](https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/eloquent-relationships) on your Enfant model. As each **Enfant** could have many **Parent**, you could do this:

**Enfant.php**

```
public function parents()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany('App\Parent');
}
```

**Parent.php**

```
public function enfants()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany('App\Enfant');
}
```

Note that Laravel will assume you have a *enfant_parent* table.

Then, you can [query the relationship existence](https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/eloquent-relationships#querying-relationship-existence) to get all parents that has enfants like this:

```
$parents = Parent::whereHas('enfants')->get();
```

**Version 2**

As you have two foreign keys, if you want to directly access the mother or the father, you could do this:

**Enfant.php**

```
public function mother()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany('App\Parent', 'enfant_parent', 'enfant_id','parent1_id');
}

public function father()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany('App\Parent', 'enfant_parent', 'enfant_id','parent2_id');
}
```

You will then be able to display parents:

```
@if($listeEnfant->mother)
    {{ $mother->name }}
@endif
@if($listeEnfant->mother)
    {{ $father->name }}
@endif
```

Comment: I apologize, I think my question was asked incorrectly,
I want to display all the information found in the children table but the problem is that I have two foreign keys parent1 and parent2 which triggers an error thank you.

Comment: how to display parent names